# One worksheet to multiple worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have one worksheet that has 8 columns in it. one of those column titles is date. I need a macro that takes all of the data and splits each day into its own workbook. is this possible? I found the below code online but code not get it to work.

```
Option Explicit

 Sub ParseItems()
'Jerry Beaucaire  (4/22/2010)
'Based on selected column, data is filtered to individual workbooks
'workbooks are named for the value plus today's date
Dim LR As Long, Itm As Long, MyCount As Long, vCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, MyArr As Variant, vTitles As String, SvPath As String

'Sheet with data in it
Set ws = Sheets("Original Data")

'Path to save files into, remember the final \
 SvPath = "C:\2010\"

'Range where titles are across top of data, as string, data MUST
'have titles in this row, edit to suit your titles locale
vTitles = "A1:Z1"

'Choose column to evaluate from, column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
vCol = Application.InputBox("What column to split data by? " & vbLf _
    & vbLf & "(A=1, B=2, C=3, etc)", "Which column?", 1, Type:=1)
If vCol = 0 Then Exit Sub

'Spot bottom row of data
LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vCol).End(xlUp).Row

'Speed up macro execution
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Get a temporary list of unique values from key column 
 ws.Columns(vCol).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,        CopyToRange:=ws.Range("EE1"), Unique:=True

'Sort the temporary list
ws.Columns("EE:EE").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("EE2"), Order1:=xlAscending,    Header:=xlYes, _
   OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom,    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

'Put list into an array for looping (values cannot be the result of formulas, must be constants)
 MyArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("EE2:EE" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))

'clear temporary worksheet list
ws.Range("EE:EE").Clear

'Turn on the autofilter, one column only is all that is needed
 ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter

 'Loop through list one value at a time
 For Itm = 1 To UBound(MyArr)
    ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter Field:=vCol, Criteria1:=MyArr(Itm)

    ws.Range("A1:A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    MyCount = MyCount + Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SvPath & MyArr(Itm) & Format(Date, " MM-DD-YY"), xlNormal
     'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SvPath & MyArr(Itm) & Format(Date, " MM-DD-YY") & ".xlsx", 51   'use for Excel 2007+
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter Field:=vCol
Next Itm

'Cleanup
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
MsgBox "Rows with data: " & (LR - 1) & vbLf & "Rows copied to other sheets:    " & MyCount & vbLf & "Hope they match!!"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "could not get it to work"? 1) You don't know what to do? - go hire a professional or go to a VBA training. b)  An error happens when you run it? - please specify so that we can help. III) Something unexpected happens? Step through the code with F8 and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - there's bound to be smaller/cleaner code, but it worked for me:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, tmp As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, usedRows As Long
Dim j As Integer, i As Integer
Dim HdrRow As Range, Rng As Range, DateCol As Range, cel As Range, xl As Range
Dim ShtArr()
'Define boundaries of worksheet, find "Date" column:
Set Sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With Sh1
        LastRow = .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set HdrRow = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastCol))

        With HdrRow
            Set Rng = .Find(What:="Date")
            If Rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Date Column not found"
                Exit Sub
            Else
               Set DateCol = .Cells(Rng.Column).EntireColumn
            End If
        End With
    End With
'Create array of dates:
Set tmp = Sheets.Add
    With tmp
        DateCol.Copy .Range("a1")
        .Range("a:a").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("b1"), Unique:=True
        .Columns(1).Delete
        .Columns(2).Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
        usedRows = .Range("a" & tmp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cel In .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(usedRows, 1))
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Format(cel, "Medium Date")
        Next cel
        ShtArr = .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(usedRows, 2))
    End With
'Add sheet for each date, and copy from original sheet:
For j = LBound(ShtArr, 1) To UBound(ShtArr, 1)
    Set Sh2 = Sheets.Add
        With Sh2
            HdrRow.Copy .Range("a1")
            .Name = (ShtArr(j, 2))
            i = 2
            For Each xl In Sh1.Range(Sh1.Cells(1, Rng.Column), Sh1.Cells(LastRow, Rng.Column))
                If xl.Value = ShtArr(j, 1) Then
                    xl.EntireRow.Copy .Range("a" & i)
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next xl
        End With
    Set Sh2 = Nothing
Next j
'Delete temporary sheet:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tmp.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't exactly an the right answer, but after a weekend of research I dove into some python and was able to do this way faster than vba. Thought I would share for anyone else thats interested.

```
import csv
import pandas as pf
import glob, os


os.chdir('/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/firstfile/')
for file in glob.glob("*python.csv"):
    print(file)

r = pf.read_csv(file)
r.head()

#prints out how many rows were searched
print r.describe()
tradeDates = r['Trade Date'].unique()

r.name = 'Trade Date'

#for loop to run through the trade dates and make new .csv files 
for trades in tradeDates:
    outfilename = trades
    printName = outfilename + ".csv"

    #prints out the file name..not necessary just gives me piece of mind
    print printName

    #makes new .csv files 
    r[r['Trade Date'] == trades].to_csv(printName)
```